# Nil Pointer Exception in Global space

Tags: go, pointers, null

I'm trying to understand the concept of pointers.

I have three packages ***main, models and controller***

in my **models.go**

```golang
type Database struct {
    config  string
    port    int
}

var DB *Database

func GetDatabase() *Database {
    fmt.Println("Reporting from Models.")
    DB = &Database{config: "This is stunning!", port: 3306}
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", DB, DB)
    return DB
}
```

in **controller.go**

```golang
var DB *models.Database = models.DB

func GetController() {
    fmt.Println("Reporting from Controllers!")
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", DB, DB)
}
```

in **main.go**

```golang
var DB *models.Database

func main() {
    DB = models.GetDatabase()
    controllers.GetController()
    fmt.Println("REporting from main")
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", DB, DB)
}
```

**The OUTPUT**

```sh
Reporting from Models.
&{This is stunning! 3306}, *models.Database
Reporting from Controllers!
<nil>, *models.Database
REporting from main
&{This is stunning! 3306}, *models.Database
```

My question here is why am I getting `nil` inside my controller for DB? My intuition is that its accessing the global DB variable at package level inside models which is `nil` since its not initiated. But since its a reference and I'm trying to give it a proper reference inside my GetDatabase function why is that change not getting reflected when I try to access that variable inside my controller?

Comment: When the `var DB *models.Database = models.DB` statement is evaluated at runtime the `models.DB` is still `nil` because `models.GetDatabase` has not yet been invoked, there's no address, so settings `DB` to `nil` will not magically update it when `models.DB` is updated, you would have to update an actual pointer.

Comment: Understood but wouldn't calling GetDatabase() update it?

Comment: No, because the assignment has already been done. If you want to update the dependent variables, then you need them to be pointers-to-pointers. I would suggest choosing a different approach than trying to have globals keep themselves in sync. As the simplest possible solution, the constant is already public so you can just directly access `database.DB` from within any other package.

Comment: What you're effectively doing is this: https://play.golang.org/p/KGgzSYHHERk

Comment: I understood it thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are essentially integers, where the number they store is the address of some other variable in memory. If you're not used to pointers, but come from a language that has arrays, it's more or less correct to think of pointers as integers holding array indexes, where  the array is memory.

When you run a statement like, this....

```
package controllers

var DB *models.Database = models.DB
```

What you're really doing here is effectively integer assignment, where the value of `models.DB` is copied by value into the variable `controllers.DB`. At the point in time where this line of code is executed, the value of `models.DB` is `nil`, so you copy the address `nil` into `controllers.DB`.

After this copy-by-value, any changes to the `models.DB` variable are completely decoupled from the `controllers.DB` variable. They're two separate things, and they both point to `nil`. Now, when you assign address of some actual `DB` instance to `models.DB`, the value of `models.DB` changes, but the unrelated variable `controllers.DB` is unaffected.

Changes to one variable (ie assignment) don't get mirrored to other variables. But, if two pointers point to the same memory, and you change the memory itself, then the changes are visible through both pointers.

If you did this...

```
models.DB = &Database{} // non-nil address
controllers.DB = models.DB // non-nil address is copied
```

then both variable would contain the same address, and changes to the single `Database` variable they both now point to would be visible through both pointers. However, reassigning the variable itself, ie `models.DB = nil`, will not affect the other variable.

Going back to the array example, you've effectively done this:

```
arr := []string{"zero", "one", "two", "three"}

idx1 := 0 // ie models.DB
idx2 := 0 // ie controllers.DB

idx1 = idx2 // copy 0 by value into idx1

idx2 = 1 // does not affect idx1, which is still 0

arr[idx1] // "zero"
arr[idx2] // "one"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share something you need a pointer, but NOT a `nil` pointer, an actual allocated one. Then you also need to use dereferencing to be able to update every instance of the shared pointer, basically dereferencing is how you update data stored at the address to which the pointer points.

```golang
var DB = &Database{}

func GetDatabase() *Database {
    // an asterisk before an expression is how you dereference a pointer
    *DB = Database{config: "This is stunning!", port: 3306}
}
```

```golang
var DB = models.DB

func GetController() {
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", DB, DB) // not nil anymore
}
```

```golang
var DB = models.DB

func main() {
    // you can ommit the assignment since GetDatabase() updates the shared 
    // pointer of models.DB
    _ = models.GetDatabase()
    fmt.Println(DB)
}
```